# Angular UI Router - Reload reverts a transitioned state back to the parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application which is role based, so I am using parent states to create layouts which are used across different roles, and then I have child states which add specific templates for the role which is necessary.

When the user authenticates the application, I am transitioning to the relevant role based state, but when you reload the page, the state is lost and it returns to the parent state.

**Example Code**

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
      'header@': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/layout/sections/auth/header.html'
      },
      'content@': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/template.html'
      },
      'left-column@dashboard': {
        templateUrl : 'partials/dashboard/left-column.html',
        controller  : 'DashNavCtrl'
      }
    },
    data: {
      layoutType: 'three-column'
    }
  })
  .state('dashboard.admin', {
    views: {
      'centre-column@dashboard': {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/recruiter/dashboard.html'
      },
      'right-column@dashboard': {
        templateUrl : 'partials/dashboard/recruiter/right-column.html',
        controller  : 'DashSidebarCtrl'
      }
    },
    data: {
      authorisedRoles: [USER_ROLES.admin]
    }
  })
```

When I transition the user to the dashboard.admin state, on reload the user gets directed back to the empty containing state.

Is it possible to stop this from happening?

Comment: You mean browser reload or just navigation? Please look my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Serhioromano/t7s3jrg4/. It uses also nested state but it saves the data that you input into fields. That is because i initialise $scope variable in the root state. And then extend it in child scopes.

Comment: browser reload. It falls back to the dashboard state. With regards to your example, how does this work '/:tab'?

Comment: I have first state abstract. I always start with that. This helps me to save data when go from state to state.

Then i create URL for every child state. This means that when states are changes, url changed too. So when user refresh or share link, it opens exactly that state. For you, just add `url` parameter to all your states.

Comment: Also read this

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing